# fbconnect in play application

Tags: playframework

I have tried this, but I dont have the facebook in my modules folder!! i have installed the fbconnect 0.6 and also the fbgraph. But my IDE shows error telling me that 'play.modules.facebook.FbGraph" couldnt be found.

Comment by project member erja...@gmail.com, May 16, 2011

```
// [...]
import play.modules.facebook.FbGraph;
import play.modules.facebook.FbGraphException;
import play.modules.facebook.Parameter;
// [...]
public class Application extends Controller {
// [...]
    public static void facebookLogin() {
        try {
            JsonObject profile = FbGraph.getObject("me"); // fetch the logged in user
            String email = profile.get("email").getAsString(); // retrieve the email
            // do useful things
            Session.current().put("username", email); // put the email into the session (for the Secure module)
        } catch (FbGraphException fbge) {
            flash.error(fbge.getMessage());


            if (fbge.getType() != null && fbge.getType().equals("OAuthException")) {
                    Session.current().remove("username");
                }
            }
            redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

help me with this please!!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so try the following:

1. add your module to the dependencies.yml
2. play deps --sync
3. play eclipsify
4. delete and reimport in eclipse

Comment: that does not work!! I still get the problem in import, I must be doing wrong help me here

Comment: Does the play deps command show any errors? Perhaps try posting to https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/playone with as much details as possible.